# Debugging Windows Command Line Syntax Error

Tags: batch-file, command-line, syntax-error

I am taking a Windows Command Line course and I am receiving an error message on my batch file that I do not understand. I am supposed to create a batch file that takes arguments and prints whether or not they are environmental variables. This is what I have so far:

```
::  Disable echoing of batch file commands to console.
@echo off

rem ********Begin Header******************
::  Author:     Megan
::  Date:   04/08/2018
::  File:   checkVars.bat
::  Descr:
::  This script determines if a given
::  set of arguments are defined
::  environmental variables.
rem ********End Header********************

::  Check to make sure at least one command
::  line argument has been given. If not,
::  display a usage message and exit the 
::  batch file. 
if "%1" == "" (
   echo Usage: %0 varname1 ...
   echo Determines if variable name is defined
   exit /b 1
)

:: determine if arguments %1 and greater
:: are environmental variables
:again
if not "%1" == "" (
   if defined %1 (
      echo %1 is a defined environment variable.
      echo.
   ) else (
      echo %1 is NOT a defined environment variable.
      echo.
   )
   shift /1
   goto again
)
```

When I run the batch file with the command *checkVars windir mydir prompt myvar*, I get the following output:

```
windir is a defined environmental variable.

mydir is NOT a defined environmental variable.

prompt is a defined environmental variable.

myvar is NOT a defined environmental variable.

The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

It looks like my code is running one extra time. Can anyone help point me in the direction of my error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at your code I noticed that you needed to enclose some parts with quotes. The main one that was causing a syntax error was `if defined %1`, where the `%1` needs to become `"%1"`. Hope that this solved your problem.

Corrected Code:

```
::  Disable echoing of batch file commands to console.
@echo off

rem ********Begin Header******************
::  Author:     Megan
::  Date:   04/08/2018
::  File:   checkVars.bat
::  Descr:
::  This script determines if a given
::  set of arguments are defined
::  environmental variables.
rem ********End Header********************

::  Check to make sure at least one command
::  line argument has been given. If not,
::  display a usage message and exit the 
::  batch file. 
if "%1" == "" (
   echo Usage: %0 varname1 ...
   echo Determines if variable name is defined
)

:: determine if arguments %1 and greater
:: are environmental variables
:again
if not "%1" == "" (
   if defined "%1" (
      echo %1 is a defined environment variable.
      echo.
   ) else (
      echo %1 is NOT a defined environment variable.
      echo.
   )
   shift /1
   goto again
)
```